# Getting a loopback address on Kali Linux using virtual box

Tags: kali-linux, virtualbox

I am trying to learn more about penetration testing which has led me to create my own secure lab.

I am using oracle virtual box to run a kali vm and to run a vulnerable web server I downloaded from vulnhub.com.

I want to make this secure so I am trying to put both these vms on their own network which is isolated from my home network. I followed a network chuck video and went into each vm to ensure they were both on "Internal Network" and I named the network "Internal". I then ran this command inside the virtual box directory,

```bash
vboxmanage dhcpserver add\
 --network=malfoy\
 --server-ip=10.38.1.1\
 --lower-ip=10.38.1.110\
 --upper-ip=10.38.1.120\
 --netmask=255.255.255.0\
 --enable
```

I then load into my kali machine and run `ip addr -a` and get a 127.0.0.1 address. How can I fix this so I am able to ping the other virtual machine.

Comment: Do you have a virtual ethernet card in your VM? Is it configured to use DHCP to obtain an address?

Comment: Kali in generally doesn't itself start to ask for IP addresses via DHCP. That would *very* much contradict its purpose of being a "silent" watcher in networks unless explicitly instructed not to. You need to manually add a connection. Although you want to learn about penetration testing, Kali might not (or it might) be the distro you need – for an attack against a webserver, any other Linux distro brings all the same tools, and in fact, is more friendly to users of VMs.

Comment: That command I ran sets up a dhcp server for the vms. How do I check if I have a virtual eth card in my vm? @ChrisDavies

Comment: @MarcusMüller I see what you are saying. I followed this video and everything worked for him. I will try adding the connection my self. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvsiuLzpx2E

Comment: Zeke if you don't know how to check these basic things may I suggest that right now Kali is not for you. Get a distribution that's more user friendly and learn with that. It'll do everything you need to do with Kali anyway

Comment: I have used ubuntu, rocky, arch, centos, redhat, and much more already. The only way to get good on kali is to use kali. I knew what you meant when you asked me if I am using a virtual eth card in my vm however, I wanted to ask where to check because I was trying to understand exactly what you were getting after. I would appreciate a response to my question in the future. @ChrisDavies Also I figured out the issue my self. For anyone who is following networkchucks video and is having issues. The solution was to use the prebuilt internal network.